# Reinstall .apk for every case with template in robotframework

Tags: apk, appium, robotframework, appium-android, reinstall

How to reinstall application for every time of test, fullReset doesnt work in this case, nor suite setup/teardown, nor test setup/teardown.

```
*** Test Cases ***

Reinstall apk
[Template]  Reinstall apk
    _test1      1test
    _test2      2test
    _test3      3test

*** Keywords ***
Reinstall apk
    [Arguments]  ${test1}     ${test2}
    Given I am on first screen
    Then I am on second screen
    ...
```

Comment: did you try noReset=false ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want reset APK every you start test just change this  parameter  to:

> **noReset=false**

:

```
 Open Application  ${APPIUM_SERVER}  platformName=${PLATFORM}  platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}   deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}  app=${APP}  automationName=${AUTOMATION_NAME}    appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}  appActivity=${APP_ACTIVITY}  noReset=false
```